# Prove that $|A+B|/|A|=|X^TA^{-1}X||X^TAX|$ when $A$ is positive definite, $B=XX^TA-AXX^T$, and $X^TX=1$.

Tags: linear-algebra

This is Problem 15 in the "Miscellaneous Exercises" section of Chapter 1 of *Matrix Differential Calculus with Applications in Statistics and Econometrics*.

Let $A$ be positive definite and let $B=XX^TA-AXX^T$ where $X^TX=1$.  Then $|X^TA^{-1}X||X^TAX|=|A+B|/|A|$, where $|A|$ denotes the determinant of $A$.

I can pretty easily show that $|X^TA^{-1}(A+B)X|=|X^TA^{-1}X||X^TAX|$, but then I get stuck.  I tried the usual tricks of diagonalizing $A$, but I'm probably just missing some "obvious" (or subtle) matrix algebra or determinant relationship.

I noticed that $X^TBX=0$, and I wonder if that's useful somewhere.  Also, we can think of $B$ as $CA-AC$ where $C$ is symmetric and idempotent -- again, not sure if that's useful.  Any help would be appreciated!  (The original paper where this problem was cited by the author of the textbook said this was true by "determinantal identities.")

Comment: If $X^TX=1$ then $X^T=X^{-1}$, from which it follows that $B=0$. You surely mean something else...

Comment: I think here $X$ is non square, so $X^{-1}$ is not defined.

Comment: A non-square matrix? $*$runs away$*$

Comment: Correct - the matrix needn't be square. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With singular value decompostion and absorption of some (exercise: which?) appropriate unitary matrices into $X$ and $A$, you may assume that $X=\pmatrix{I_n\\ 0}$. Write $A=\pmatrix{P&Q\\ R&S}$ where $P$ has the same size as $I_n$ (and $R=Q'$ because $A$ is positive definite, but this is unimportant here). Note that $X^TA^{-1}X$ is the leading principal block of $A^{-1}$, which is equal to $(P-QS^{-1}R)^{-1}$, i.e. the inverse of the [Schur complement](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schur_complement) of $S$ in $\widetilde{A}$. So, you can reduce the equality in question to
$$
\det(P) \det(S) / \det(A) = \det(P-QS^{-1}R)^{-1} \det(P),
$$
i.e.
$$
\det(A^{-1}) = \det(P-QS^{-1}R)^{-1} \det(S^{-1}).
$$
Now the latter is a well-known determinantal identity for expressing the determinant of the inverse of a matrix using Schur complement. (See the Wikipedia link in the above for a proof.)

Comment: Thanks for this!  I'll have a thorough look through, but to be clear, how are you applying this to the sum in question?  That is: $A^{-1}(A+B)$?

Comment: @RicLouRiv When $X=\pmatrix{I_n\\ 0}$, you have $\det(A+B)=\det(P)\det(S)$ (write down $A+B$ in terms of $P,Q,R,S$ and you will see this), $\det(X^TA^{-1}X)=\det(P-QS^{-1}R)^{-1}$, etc..

Comment: So cool!  I follow the argument, but I just need to convince myself now about your first claim (using SVD and other matrix decompositions to allow $X = (I_n \, 0)^T$.  Thanks again!

Comment: Ok, I think I see it.  Write $X=UDV^T$.  Then $XX^TA-AXX^T=UDD^TU^TA-AUDD^TU^T$, and $A+B=A+UDD^TU^TA-AUDD^TU^T$.  Then $U^T(A+B)U=U^TAU+DD^TU^TAU-U^TAUDD^T$.  Since $|U^T(A+B)U|=|A+B|$, we can compute the right hand side assuming $A:=U^TAU$ and $D$ as the form you have it.